# Programmatically specify a download location for different file types using the WebView2 control for WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

Does anybody know how to specify a download location for specific file types when downloading them through the WebView2 control?

Example:

PDF files go to `D:\PDF`, and Excel files go to `D:\Excel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can only specify a download location when using a WebClient programatically, which can only download from a specific url eg.

```
WebClient WB = new WebClient();
WB.DownloadFile("http://example.com/example.txt", @"d:\example.txt");
```

WebView is meant to be a WebBrowser control based on chromium, it will act like a web browser unless you directly modify it (source code).

So to answer your question, there is not a way to specify a download location for a specific file type using the WebView2 control.

You can however build yourself a downloader, which downloads files to a specific location from a url using the WebClient in C#.

Comment: One could use the `NavigationStarted` event to do the download processing outside of the WebView, but it would lose session context (cookies etc) and you'd have to be able to distinguish download links from other links before actually making the request (so you can't for example look at the MIME Content-Type header in the response).

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the [`DownloadStarting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.downloadstarting?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1587.40) event to intercept downloads and set the [`ResultFilePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2downloadstartingeventargs.resultfilepath?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1587.40) on the event `args` depending on the download object's [`MimeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2downloadoperation.mimetype?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1587.40#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2downloadoperation-mimetype). The download object is also accessed through the event `args`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to the **CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted** event, or you can also handle that at the Form's constructor:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += webView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;                
    }
```

There change the [DefaultDownloadFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2profile.defaultdownloadfolderpath?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1343.22) property of **webView2.CoreWebView2.Profile** to the path you want.

```
private void webView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string folderName = (savingPDF)? "PDF":(savingExcel)?"Excel":"Other";
        webView.CoreWebView2.Profile.DefaultDownloadFolderPath = "C:\\" + folderName;
    }
```

Notice that, (with enough privileges) the directory is created if it does not yet exist.